# Terminal not responding in Cloud9 IDE Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

I'm working my way through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial, and suddenly the terminal is not responding to common commands.

Entering commands like "bundle exec rake test" or "rails console" creates the situation in the screenshot below and waiting hours does not change anything.

http://i59.tinypic.com/2poz5ah.png

I can type on the line but the Terminal still doesn't respond to any commands here. Ctrl+C allows me to escape the previous request and get back to the command line.

Strangely, "git status" works fine and quick.

Any ideas how to fix this?

I've tried restarting the Terminal and re-loading the workspace.

Comment: you should report this to cloud9 support team, better help there

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem two times (also going thru the Rails Tutorial) and here's how I went about adressing it:

Click on the workspace button in the top right corner- that's where it shows your CPU, Memory & Disk Usage (if you're on a laptop/small screen zoom out or make the screen as wide as possible to view that).

Next click on the "show process" button to see active processes.

After that I "force killed" my bash and ruby processes.

Lastly I clicked the "restart" button, which you see that when you first clicked to see the workspace info. Please note that if I went first to clicking this "restart" it had no effect... I had to force kill... THEN resart...

Viola, two times now it worked!

Not sure if this has any impact, but both times I mentally retraced my steps and realized I had several terminal windows open and willy-nilly ran the console multiple times in different terminal windows over the course of a few days. I would then run into not being able to run rails c UNLESS I have previously "properly" exited an already running console (meaning ctrl-c).

I've run into something similar while running Rails on my machine, and a full system restart does the trick. Perhaps due to the cloud based nature of Rails on Cloud9 there is some "sticky" process that stays on?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that on my machine I would also run "killall ruby" in a new terminal window. While that didn't work on Cloud9 it may be worth a try!

Anyhoo- lemme know if that does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Please do report these kind of (performance) questions to our Support desk via https://support.c9.io - we'll be able to help you quickly! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what I did is just killed that process

ubuntu    5318  0.0  0.0 488820 16872 pts/3    Sl   Dec24   0:01 spring server

kill -9 5318

You will have ur pid number. so just use it.
to get process -- use :

ps aux

Answer (score 0):

Executing "bin/spring stop" would solve the issue as well. It is currently unknown why this happens and we are looking into that.